# How to handle when DatabindingImpl and Parcelable class retain in memory after app closed?

Tags: android, android-studio, heap-dump, android-profiler, retained-in-memory

After app close few classes retain in memory. App application (@HiltAndroidApp), DataBindingImpl and Language class which extend Parcelable retain in memory. How to handle this issue?
Please see the attached memory heap dump in memory profiler.
[image: memory heap dump in memory profiler]

Comment: Could you fully expand the reference chain? What's holding `CREATOR`?